# Using protocols with the newest @Environment in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I'm using the latest Observation framework with SwiftUI introduced at WWDC 2023. It seems that the new `@Environment` property wrapper does not allow to use protocols. Here is what my service implementations looks like:

```swift
protocol UserServiceRepresentation {
    var user: User { get }
}

// Service implementation
@Observable
final class UserService: UserServiceRepresentable {
    private(set) var user: User

    func fetchUser() async { ... }
}

// Service mock
@Observable
final class UserServiceMock: UserServiceRepresentable {
    let user: User = .mock
}
```

Previously, it was possible using `@EnvironmentObject` to declare a protocol so you can pass your mocked service as your environment object to the view.

```swift
struct UserView: View {
    // This is possible using EnvironmentObject.
    // But it require UserService to conforms to ObservableObject.
    @EnvironmentObject private var userService: UserService

    var body: some View { ... }
}

#Preview {
    UserView()
        .environmentObject(UserServiceMock()) // this allows your previews not to rely on production data.
}
```

Now, with `@Environment`, I can't do something like this:

```swift
struct UserView: View {
    // This is not possible
    // Throw compiler error: No exact matches in call to initializer
    @Environment(UserService.self) private var userService

    var body: some View { ... }
}
```

I would have been nice to inject my mocked user service like so:

```swift
#Preview {
    UserView()
        .environment(UserServiceMock())
}
```

Am I missing something or doing it the wrong way? It seems that the new `@Environment` property wrapper was not built for this kind of usage. I can't find anything about it on the web. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The new `@Environment` should take an `Observable`-conforming type, and no, protocols cannot conform to other protocols, so it can't be used this way. What's wrong with how you previously did this anyway?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the previous way. The `@EnvironmentObject` way allowed me not to make singleton for shared objects in the app to better deal with dependencies injection. The new `@Environment` now forces me to create singletons. It works that way, but I feel like a regression.

Comment: Nothing is forcing you to do anything. You can keep using `@EnvironmentObject` and `ObservableObject`. They are not deprecated or anything. Do you mean you don't want to use `ObservableObject` anymore for some other reason, but still wants a convenient dependency injection?

Comment: You can make UserServiceMock a subclass of UserService, wrap it inside `#if DEBUG ... #endif` if you want to be sure it isn't used anywhere in the app code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this could indeed work. But I’d prefer using composition over inheritance.

Comment: This is just for using in a preview so for me it wouldn’t be an issue to use inheritance even if normally also prefer composition

Comment: Observable is for a model, for a service use EnvironmentKey

Comment: @Sweeper I came across the same issue. The reason I prefer Observable over ObservableObject is that the latter will re-render all views depending on one of the Published properties, whereas changes on an Observable's properties only cause a re-render if that particular property is used by the view. That's a major performance gain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `@Environment` initialisers take a *concrete* type that is `Observable`, and there is nothing wrong with keep using `EnvironmentObject` and `ObservableObject`. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

If you really like `@Observable` for some reason, you can create a custom environment key that stores the user service. The value for the environment key can be an existential protocol type.

```
struct UserServiceKey: EnvironmentKey {
    // you can also set the real user service as the default value
    static let defaultValue: any UserServiceRepresentation = UserServiceMock()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var userService: any UserServiceRepresentation {
        get { self[UserServiceKey.self] }
        set { self[UserServiceKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Then you can call the `Environment` initialiser that takes a keypath.

```
@Environment(\.userService) var service
```

```
.environment(\.userService, someService)
```

Note that if the instance of `UserServiceRepresentation` is not `Observable`, this will not work. It might be better to require an `Observable` conformance.

```
protocol UserServiceRepresentation: Observable
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is a working solution. The Observation framework provide several features such as performance improvements and Apple strongly encourage developers to migrate. That being said, you’re right saying that still using @EnvironmentObject to this day would not cause any issue.

Comment: I believe this won't send change notifications though because existential types aren't equatable

Comment: @aehlke What can change? Setting `user` from within `UserService` does cause the view to update correctly, and changing the environment value to something else works too. If something is not working for you, you should post a new question and include a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, you're right - nice trick for getting view updates from an existential type